# Low loss and low accuracy. What is the reason?

Tags: neural-networks, accuracy, loss-functions, cross-entropy

We have trained two different neural networks for MNIST dataset. Here are the losses and accuracies obtained by these networks for the training data:

```
net0: loss: 20780.8291187
net1: loss: 209.928699374
net0: TRAIN ACCURACY     0.985890040888
net1: TRAIN ACCURACY     0.835298627336
```

The used loss function is the cross-entropy. We expect higher accuracies for lower losses, but here, the loss for `net1` is about 100 times lower than `net0` but its accuracy is lower. What is the reason?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256551/why-does-the-accuracy-not-change-when-applying-different-alpha-values-in-l2-reg/256554#256554

Comment: @Sycorax Thanks. So if cross-entropy is so fragile that it can be completely different from accuracy, why we rely on it so much?

Comment: "Fragile" is the wrong word, to my mind. Cross entropy measures how well-calibrated a model is. Accuracy is scarcely informative because many poorly or well calibrated models can have the same accuracy.

Comment: @Sycorax But here I have a model that has lower cross-entropy loss, but with **lower** accuracy. They don't have the same accuracy.

Comment: It's not clear to me why that's a problem. Q: "Which model has better accuracy?" A: "net0" Q: "Which model has better cross-entropy?" A: "net1" Q: "Why?" A: "Accuracy and cross-entropy measure different things."

Comment: @Sycorax Here is what I think: Our ultimate goal, at least in a problem like digit recognition, is to obtain better accuracies. So, if a loss function disagrees with the accuracy, it is not so reliable. In other words, if a model with a lower accuracy can get the lower cross-entropy loss, this means that the cross-entropy can mislead us since we are optimizing this loss function to obtain better accuracies.

Comment: If all you care about is accuracy, a better accuracy is better.

Answer (score 6):

Lower cost function error not means better accuracy.
The error of the cost function represents how well your model is learning/able to learn with respect to your training examples.

Now the question is , 
Is the model learning something that I expect it to learn?

It can show very low learning curves error but when you actually testing the results (Accuracy) you are getting wrong detection's , this is called high variance.

The best is to monitor the both learning error and accuracy for each epoch/iteration, While cost function error goes down and accuracy goes up keep training, otherwise stop (:

The accuracy is not good enough? check : 
1. do I have high variance problem ? add more training examples to generalize the learning (better find more examples which reminds the problems where your model fails on).

2. Do I have high bias problem ? my model is pure or to complex , need to fix it / try something else.

http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/10_Advice_for_applying_machine_learning.html

Good luck (:

Comment: you are missing the point here. Bias is measured on Train Set and Variance is measures on Validation set. Instead, the question is: why in my training set I have a small cross-entropy loss but bad accuracy.